# Groovy - WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

Tags: java, groovy

I am pretty much new to java and groovy. I have installed groovy 3.0 on my windows 10 laptop (64 bit) and when tried to run groovy getting following warning:

```
>groovy -v
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/C:/groovy-3.0.0-alpha-1/lib/groovy-3.0.0-alpha-1.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Groovy Version: 3.0.0-alpha-1 JVM: 9.0.1 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 10
```

And the java version is:

```
java --version
java 9.0.1
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

Any help to resolve this.

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. Won't hurt you.

Comment: Does it works without any issues going forward ? Is there any way to sort out this ?

Comment: It'll cause issues at *some* point in the future, but not yet. As the message says, you can report this to the library maintainers... **if** you're using the latest version, and a bug report doesn't already exist.

Comment: Groovy is having to undergo significant changes to accommodate the Java 9 module system; this is why the version is labeled `alpha-1`. If you're new to Groovy and Java, start with Groovy 2.4 (and probably Java 8) to get acquainted before dealing with modules.

Comment: @chrylis: Sure, will proceed as suggested.

Comment: I hope it may be ignored for now because it is warning nor error. Please se upstream bugreport for that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8339

Comment: I am getting this error with Groovy v2.4.15 under JDK 1.8 -- I've seen several comments citing Java 9.  I get it from 1.8, 10 and 11 (I skipped 9 just like Oracle did).

Comment: I have the same when using Java 11. Using Java 8 does not show this warning.

Comment: _"If you think something's supposed to hurt, you're less likely to notice if you're doing it wrong." -- Paul Graham_.  @shmosel: sure, a warning won't directly stop something from working, but making a habit of ignoring warnings is... I'd argue... "doing it wrong".  Things shouldn't generate warnings unless someone is supposed to actually pay attention to them.  And then if a warning is generated, we should actually pay attention.  The fact that this is not a norm that's widely practiced _does_ hurt various people in various ways, some big, mostly small (like wasted time here!)

Answer (score 9):

To disable the warnings you can pass `--add-opens` to the JVM, see details [here](https://blog.codefx.org/java/five-command-line-options-hack-java-module-system/#Reflectively-Accessing-Internal-APIs-With--add-opens). Unfortunately Groovy requires *a lot* of modules/packages to be opened, see this (currently reverted) [commit](https://github.com/apache/groovy/commit/92bd96fcdfe35e502987e1846715a08a45620db1) ([source](http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.5.html#Groovy2.5releasenotes-Knownissues)). Just tested these with AdoptOpenJDK 11.

Answer (score 8):

It is more than a 'warning' for me: I cannot get Groovy scripts to run (on macOS) with the current JVM 9, much less 10. The workaround (until a compatible version of Groovy is available) is to install jenv and an earlier version of Java, so you can switch when needed.

Comment: The reason it might not work is explained here.  Basically, Java changed some runtime rules that break/prevent Groovy's introspection of some private methods.   https://superuser.com/a/1438336/331605

Answer (score 5):

Setting `JAVA_HOME` to a Version 8 JRE solved it for me:

```
#! /usr/bin/env -S JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre groovy
println "hello world"
```

Answer (score 4):

Although my environment is Linux, after struggling some days to setup Groovy on Grails environment I feel like I know the answer: use JDK 8 for now. I was fiddling with JDK 9, and I thought it was too far behind so I tried JDK 11, which made things even worse, I got actual crashes. It seems like that Groovy / Grails is heavily lagging behind in terms of Java version compatibility.

Once the new Groovy will be released (said to be end of this year) then newer JDK can be used as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Java 8, however, if the java version must be 9 or >, you need to update the groovy version too.

I was running groovy 2.2.1 and it only works until java version 8

Answer (score 1):

add groovy-version to your pom:

```
        <groovy.version>3.0.4</groovy.version>
```

Comment: How come that this misleading hint got two points? Yes, it may work iff (a) Maven is used and (b) groovy's version is indirectly specified as ${groovy.version}.

Comment: Btw, I'm using `groovy-3.0.7.jar` and java 11 (graal vm) and problem is still around.

Comment: I am using jdk8 with maven, my groovy version was nowhere specified but adding this to my pom.xml solved the issue for me:    <dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
   <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.8</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with openjdk 11.0.15 2022-04-19 and Groovy 2.4.17 on Linux Mint 20.1

```
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Groovy Version: 2.4.17 JVM: 11.0.15 Vendor: Private Build OS: Linux
```

To fix it I installed Jabba
https://github.com/shyiko/jabba

First you need to set which version of Jabba you want to install:

```
export JABBA_VERSION=0.11.2
```

Then run the curl command:

```
curl -sL https://github.com/shyiko/jabba/raw/master/install.sh | bash && . ~/.jabba/jabba.sh
Installing v0.11.2...

Adding source string to /home/spock/.bashrc
Adding source string to /home/spock/.profile
Installation completed
```

```
spock@hp-compaq-a:~/workspace/test/groovy-examples/hello-world$ jabba
Java Version Manager (https://github.com/shyiko/jabba).

Usage:
  jabba [flags]
  jabba [command]

Available Commands:
  install     Download and install JDK
  uninstall   Uninstall JDK
  link        Resolve or update a link
  unlink      Delete a link
  use         Modify PATH & JAVA_HOME to use specific JDK
  current     Display currently 'use'ed version
  ls          List installed versions
  ls-remote   List remote versions available for install
  deactivate  Undo effects of `jabba` on current shell
  alias       Resolve or update an alias
  unalias     Delete an alias
  which       Display path to installed JDK
```

```
spock@hp-compaq-a:~/workspace/test/groovy-examples/hello-world$ jabba ls
zulu@1.8.275

spock@hp-compaq-a:~/workspace/test/groovy-examples/hello-world$ jabba use zulu@1.8.275

spock@hp-compaq-a:~/workspace/test/groovy-examples/hello-world$ jabba current
zulu@1.8.275

spock@hp-compaq-a:~/workspace/test/groovy-examples/hello-world$ groovy -v
Groovy Version: 2.4.17 JVM: 1.8.0_275 Vendor: Azul Systems, Inc. OS: Linux
```

See this video for a good concise introduction to what Jabba can do:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2kYVCCeIMo

Comment: I like the idea of jabba.  The underlying reason that it Groovy breaks is due to changes in the Java runtime, explained here https://superuser.com/a/1438336/331605.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I was using JUNIT 5 with groovy but the latest supported I found is JUNIT 4.13