# how to disable a warning in groovyscript?

Tags: groovy

when i run my groovy script on console, every time i get below warnings,
how i can disable this comments ??

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/usr/share/groovy/lib/groovy-2.4.16.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access  operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935772/groovy-warning-an-illegal-reflective-access-operation-has-occurred

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using java 9 or higher

To remove this warning add the following java parameter into groovy bat/shell

```
--illegal-access=permit
```

Or define environment variable

```
JAVA_OPTS=--illegal-access=permit
```

More info about this and other java parameters:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624

BTW, one of the options - switch to java8

Comment: still same output..

Comment: What exactly have you done?

Comment: i had first run the JAVA_OPTS=--illegal-access=permit ,then run my script.

Comment: What operating system do you have?

Comment: i have lnux os.

Comment: It depends on shell, but try `export JAVA_OPTS="--illegal-access=permit"`

Comment: no changes bro , still same output.

Comment: How you are starting groovy?  Try to find in groovy binaries following script and add this option directly to java start line just before $JAVA_OPTS. https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/bin/startGroovy#L264