# groovy WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred under Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, groovy, java-11

Same issue as
[Groovy - WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935772/groovy-warning-an-illegal-reflective-access-operation-has-occurred), just that

- This is in Ubuntu 21.10
- And most importantly that solution (of passing `--add-opens` to the JVM), I'm not able to make it working for me.

```sh
$ groovy -version
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/usr/share/groovy/lib/groovy-2.4.21.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Groovy Version: 2.4.21 JVM: 11.0.12 Vendor: Ubuntu OS: Linux

$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.12+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu3, mixed mode, sharing)

$ java --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -version
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.12+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu3, mixed mode, sharing)

$ groovy --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -version
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/usr/share/groovy/lib/groovy-2.4.21.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Caught: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /export/home/me/--add-opens (/export/home/me/--add-opens)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /export/home/me/--add-opens (/export/home/me/--add-opens)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

$ apt-cache policy groovy
groovy:
  Installed: 2.4.21-1
  Candidate: 2.4.21-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.4.21-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status


$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:        21.10
Codename:       impish
```

**Update,** I've tried to set `JAVA_OPTS` as well:

```sh
export JAVA_OPTS="--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"

$ groovy -version
Unrecognized option: --add-opens
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

How to get rid of that warning message?

Comment: Groovy 2.4.21 has a number of these issues. Groovy 2.5 and 3 and very soon 4 each make strides to use method handles and other proper access mechanisms.

Comment: to work with java 11 better to use groovy 3.0. java 9 started to be supported in groovy 2.5. groovy 2.4 designed for java 8. https://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.5.html

Comment: Thanks @daggett, I think you've nailed it. Just that my latest Ubuntu 21.10 is still only providing groovy-2.4.21. And for this particular reason, I think I'll use the java 8 (provided by openjdk-8-jdk:amd64) instead of installing groovy 3.0 using the external `sdkman` tool, because I just need something to work, no need to be the latest and greatest, and java 8 is fine with me. THX!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clear from the FileNotFound exception that the --add-opens was not used as a JVM flag.
Have you tried setting JAVA_OPTS?  Like so:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"
groovy --version
```

I don't get the same error as you.  I actually still get the reflective access warnings, not an error about `--add-opens` being unrecognized.
Even with `--illegal-access=permit` I still see the warnings. Odd.  I'm sure the JAVA_OPTS value is being used as it does complain if I set it to an invalid flag.

Do you have JAVA_HOME defined? I noticed groovy also picks up that value to choose the JVM.

With Java 17 I get no warnings or errors.

Comment: It seems that --add-opens isn't enough.  I've updated my answer as I get a different result from you.  And I see groovy doesn't complain with Java 17.

Comment: thx, can you list your java / groovy versions and your OS details as well pls?

Comment: @xpt Java 17.0.1,  groovy 2.4.17, Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: thx, and _"I actually still get the reflective access warnings"_, what's the Java version for that pls?

Comment: @xpt Was still getting the warnings with JVM 11.0.13

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions here: https://groovy-lang.org/install.html
This will:

- Install sdkman

  - Manages multiple JDKs and extensions
- Install groovy in the current JDK

Worked for me on:

- openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)